# Spinner works in 2.3 but not 3.2

Tags: android, spinner

I have been successfully running an app under android 2.2 (api8) using spinners with OnItemSelectedListeners. It was built with tarketSdkVersion = 8 and minSdkVersion = 8. I am now trying to run it on a 3.2 device, but the spinners can not be selected. They do populate with the default array value however, so the adapter appears to be working. Clicking on the spinners results in no reaction. I tried building with tarketSdkVersion = 13 and minSdkVersion = 13, but the spinners are still dead. I am using slightly customized spinner versions to achieve "wrap_content" in a multiline_spinner_dropdown_item.xml file. Is there a compatibility issue with spinners since 2.2?

Comment: any errors? if so, please post stacktrace

Comment: no errors, in fact the rest of the app controls work...and still the spinners do not respond to a click. In debug, the OnItemSelectedListeners never fire.

Comment: Can you please post some your code? So i can try it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the .setEnabled(true) but it didn't work. In frustration, I started to remove sections of code from main.java and layout.xml until a single spinner was left and working. As I added the code and controls back, I found that a ScrollView nestled inside a TabHost/LinearLayout/TabWidget/FrameLayout prevented the Spinners from responding. By removing the Scrollview, the Spinners worked in 3.2. For some reason the Scrollview worked in 2.2, but not 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I used the spinner in 2.2 ,it was working but the same do not work in 3.2, The problem was with the default theme of 3.2, its holo. because of that the spinner is not shown properly,
Just create a theme in values/style, and apply it to your activity in android.manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance changing the visibility of the spinner?

I had a similar problem, and it was necessary to call `setAdapter()` every time the spinner was re-shown, otherwise it became immune to clicks.

You can see the change I made to my project that fixed this problem at https://github.com/nikclayton/android-squeezer/commit/7a148edf5f1b3eaca7718161de18254970290ce0.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some visibility issues ? 
Are you stacking the ScrollView on top of the area where the spinners' items show up ?
Try to use different states for the spinners by changing their icon or color for example and see if they get the click event. If they do, then it is probably something related with visibility. If they don't, it might something else. 
Some code sample could help :)

Comment: Oddly, I tried another app of my that works great on 2.2. When I installed it on a 3.1 tablet or emulator, the onClick events won't fire. No spinners this time, but the listeners don't work either!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the spinner as enabled?

```
spinner.setEnabled(true);
```

Although it would be weird that it was disabled on default.  Your symptoms do describe a disabled spinner though

Answer (score 0):

Oddly, I tried another app of my that works great on 2.2. When I installed it on a 3.1 tablet or emulator, the onClick events won't fire. No spinners this time, but the listeners don't work either! Here's some of the code:

```
//In onCreate:

//setup listeners
rbSlab = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbSlab);
rbBeam = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.rbBeam);
rbSlab.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
rbBeam.setOnClickListener(radio_listener);
etFpc.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
etFy.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
etBw.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
etDp.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
etMu.setOnEditorActionListener(this);
...
}//end onCreate

//In Main body of app:
//for radio buttons
private OnClickListener radio_listener = new View.OnClickListener()
{   //@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DoCalcs();
    }//onClick
};

//for edittext
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) 
    {   if ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) || //if DONE button pushed
            ((event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&           (event.getKeyCode()    == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))) //if ENTER button pushed
    {
        //do calcs

        return(true);
            }
        else return(false);
    }
```

I've built this with target API 8 and min API 8, and also with target API 14, min 8, and when installed on a API 8 the listeners work fine, but not with API 14!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It's because of the default theme of Android 3.2 and above versions.

The simpler solution is to use a custom spinner, or to make any background colour or picture for the same, like:

```
android:background="@drawable/spinner"
```

This [link](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Spinner_With_Image_And_Text_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=84&aaid=107) will help you for custom spinner.